# How do I enable syntax highlighting for Fortran in GitBook

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gitbook

#### Original Question:

I can't find how to activate syntax highlighting on GitBook!
It works perfectly when I look at the `.md` files on GitHub where my repository is hosted, by not when I look at my rendered gitbook on the web.
Any ideas? Thanks

#### Edit:

it works for bash, Python, C, C++, javascript, etc, but not for Fortran! It seems that gitbook and github don't use the same syntax highlighting package.
Is there a way to activate syntax highlighting with Fortran on GitBook?

#### Sample code:

````
``` fortran
program compute_t
    implicit none

    integer :: d1, d2, d3, d4 d5  ! Input data
    integer :: u1, u2, v, w, t    ! Computed entities

    call read_data(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5)

    call compute_u(d1,d2,u1)
    call compute_u(d3,d4,u2)
    call compute_w(d5,w)
    call compute_v(u2,w,v)
    call compute_t(u1,v,t)

    write(*,*), "t=", t

end program
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GitBook's own documentation, which is [available as a GitBook](http://help.gitbook.io/), [uses named fenced code blocks](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GitbookIO/documentation/master/book/markdown.md) as [popularized by GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#syntax-highlighting):

````
```markdown
# H1
## H2
### H3
#### H4
##### H5
###### H6
```
````

Although I can't find any documentation that explicitly says this is supported, I suspect that it works just fine.

**Edit:**

> it works for bash, Python, C, C++, javascript, etc, but not for Fortran! It seems that gitbook and github don't use the same syntax highlighting package.

GitHub uses a Ruby library called [Linguist](https://github.com/github/linguist#syntax-highlighting) for syntax highlighting. It [looks like GitBook uses](https://github.com/GitbookIO/gitbook/blob/e1594cde2c32e4ff48f6c4eff3d3d461743d74e1/package.json#L19) the JavaScript library [`highlight.js`](https://highlightjs.org/), which [doesn't support Fortran](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js/tree/master/src/languages).

> Is there a way to activate syntax highlighting with Fortran on GitBook?

Short of contributing Fortran support to `highlight.js`, I don't think there's a good solution for this at the moment.